# Video streming with media player

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm a new developer and I would like my app to be able to stream videos. I basicly want it to work like youtube, to be able to stream videos from its own database/server (don't really know how it works yet). I searched a bit for a way to stream a youtube video from the media player, and found the code below in few places.
I've also added a VideoView in the xml file. But it seems to have some kind of problem and I really don't know what is it. The only differance in the code from what I found is that I've modified it to work from a fragment and not from an activity because as for now my app contains only one activity and four three fragments.

So I have 2 questions: 1. Does anyone know whats the problem with my implemantation? 2. Is this how I interact with a server ,if I had all my videos on that server - just by writing the url? Thanks.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class main_page extends Fragment {
    public main_page() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        VideoView videoView=(VideoView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vvMainPage);


        MediaController mc=new MediaController(getActivity());
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);

        String str="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvEZUbzqqyM";
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(str);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.start();
        videoView.requestFocus();


    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
04-24 18:00:59.956: W/EGL_emulation(1905): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-24 18:01:00.128: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb989d8b8): name, size, mSize = 242, 1048576, 1100992
04-24 18:01:00.352: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98a8d48): name, size, mSize = 244, 100, 1101092
04-24 18:01:00.476: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98957e8): name, size, mSize = 246, 7488, 1108580
04-24 18:01:03.620: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb9899820): name, size, mSize = 255, 7488, 1116068
04-24 18:01:05.500: D/getUser (dev)(1905): First name: dev Last name: dev Email: dev@dev.com Username: dev Password: 123
04-24 18:01:05.616: W/EGL_emulation(1905): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-24 18:01:05.640: D/MediaPlayer(1905): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-24 18:01:05.652: E/MediaPlayer(1905): Unable to to create media player
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905): Unable to open content: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvEZUbzqqyM
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:958)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:946)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:899)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:235)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:51)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:478)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:671)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1818)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 18:01:05.656: D/VideoView(1905): Error: 1,0
04-24 18:01:05.808: W/EGL_emulation(1905): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-24 18:01:05.820: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98aea90): name, size, mSize = 263, 19008, 1135076
04-24 18:01:05.832: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98aa748): name, size, mSize = 264, 19008, 1154084
04-24 18:01:05.844: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb989d1d0): name, size, mSize = 265, 4, 1154088
04-24 18:01:07.248: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98acd60): name, size, mSize = 282, 324, 1154412
04-24 18:01:09.852: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::flush: target size: 692647
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 246, 7488, 1146924
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 255, 7488, 1139436
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 244, 100, 1139336
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 282, 324, 1139012
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 263, 19008, 1120004
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 264, 19008, 1100996
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 265, 4, 1100992
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 242, 1048576, 52416
```

Comment: First of all your class name should always starts with capital and there should not be any special characters in class name. Secondly you should parse the uri in background thread and not on main thread

Comment: First of all thank's. I will change the nema of the calss, I wasn't aware to this.
But I didn't understand what you said about the main thread and backgroud thread.
As far as I know I don't use threads now..
Can you explain a bit more about that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("first_uri");
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't wotk. Logcat shows:
04-26 15:35:29.874: E/MediaPlayer(8832): Unable to to create media player

Comment: you didn't use 
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
please try again, my player works fine :)

Comment: Well you are absolutely right! The problem was the requestFocus for some reason.
But it worked only now and now the app crashes... Do I need to terminate the streming maybe?

Comment: maybe, you didn't add permissions in manifest file?
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>
add this permission into your manifest file or tell me your email address and i'll send you codes

Comment: It's working now. But now I'm trying to understand if theres a way that i can stream media from a website URL like to stream movies from youtube?